# check duplication while inserting through detailsview c#

Tags: c#, detailsview

I have a details view and a button, and when I click on the button, I want to check if the username is already in the database or not.

I tried the below code and I tested it with button and it worked, but know I want to assign it to the insert command of the detailsview. I tried to put it in DetailsView1_ItemInserting but in case of if statement it gives me this [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzk9r.jpg), but in case of else statement is works fine.

I want to show an error message instead of the error page, my question is where should i put my code .. Any Help??

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string query = "select Username from [Login] where Username = '" + ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dr.Read();
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
            {

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Username is Already Exists')</script>");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('SuccessFully Saved')</script>");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What does the error message say? And what is the line of code that's causing the error message?

Comment: @Rufus L I attached a picture to the question... I want to show an error message instead of the error page, my question is where should i put my code